# Bad image quality when setting a UIImageView from URL String

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I made a group chat app so that when you tap on a person's avatar next to their chat bubble, it takes you to a profile page where you can see their profile picture fullscreen.

In the profile controller, I have

```
self.profileImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(self.profileAvatar)
```

in viewDidLoad, with `self.profileAvatar` being a URL String to the user's Facebook profile picture. This is the image loading function I'm using:

```
let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()

extension UIImageView {

func loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(_ urlString: String) {

    self.image = nil

    // Check cache for image first
    if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as NSString) {
        self.image = cachedImage
        return
    }

    // Otherwise fire off a new download
    Alamofire.request(urlString)
        .responseImage { response in

            if let downloadedImage = response.result.value {
                // image is here.
                imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: urlString as NSString)
                self.image = downloadedImage
            }
    }
}
}
```

When I tap on an avatar to see the fullscreen image, the quality is awful. I have it set to `.scaleAspectFill`. Is there anything I can do to improve the image quality?

Comment: Probably not. Try to display your image in Safari using the url. You're not getting anything better than that. What you probably can do however, it get a different url to a better quality image (look into the Facebook api for that).

Comment: I'd rather not go out of the app into Safari. It's just funny because elsewhere in the app, when the image is smaller (avatar size), the quality looks great. I guess it's just a crappy image that looks ok when small and bad when scaled up? I just didn't realize the Facebook profile pic URL was leading to a bad quality version of the image.

Comment: I was only suggesting opening the url in Safari as a test to check the quality of your image, which is probably the issue. The Facebook api offers a way to get different quality levels for the profile picture.

Comment: Yeah, when I open the URL in safari the image is pretty small, even when specifying that I want the large size in the graph request.